# What could have caused this big hole in my brick wall?

Tags: brick, crack

The house is 2 years old.
What could have caused this big hole? Brick is crumbling and cracking.

[image]

Comment: No image provided

Comment: Two year old house should still be in warranty.  Take pictures and contact the builder.  Would not hurt to have the local building have a look also.

Comment: It is impossible for anyone here to help without a pic or 2

Comment: That should have been local building inspector.  My bad.

Comment: why does this look like a CMYK offset print of a captcha?

Comment: Excellent question, @Yorik - it looks more like "black stuff on brick" than "empty hole in brick" but zooming in does not make it any clearer, and raises exactly that question.

Comment: The photo is likely taken of a printed home inspection report. Source: have purchased too many homes recently.

Comment: could be a frost cleave, it does source right under a drip-collecting corner.

Comment: Where are you located? It's an odd configuration and from the cracking in the caulk under the window it's clear something has moved. I also can't quite identify the metal(?) angle trim with the small hole, next to the brickwork?